# Problem with SE-Toolkit cloning website

Tags: vmware

I have been trying to do some things on se-toolkit and when I clone a website it says:

```
[!] Apache may be not running, do you want SET to start the process? [y/n]: y
[....] Starting web server: apache2httpd (pid 11995) already running
. ok 
Apache webserver is set to ON. Copying over PHP file to the website.
Please note that all output from the harvester will be found under apache_dir/harvester_date.txt
Feel free to customize post.php in the /var/www directory
```

I can't locate `/var/www`

Any ideas? Thanks

PS: I'm on VMware

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal and type:

```
locate /var/www
```

the output should look similar to this:

```
/var/www

/var/www/harvester_2014-09-26 06:15:41.015049.txt

/var/www/index.html

/var/www/index.html~

/var/www/post.php
```

choose you favorite file-manager and navigate to the directory.

Or type this in your terminal:

```
gksudo nautilus /var/www
```

[gksudo][file-manager][directory]

[image: sorry for this ugly picture]

Or even better, use a text-editor and edit the file right from the terminal like so:

```
sudo nano /var/www/post.php
```

or

```
gksudo gedit gedit /var/www/post.php
```